# Grouping objects by property value

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, grouping

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this out. I have a list of objects with two properties: `Alias` and `Value`

I need to show a list of these objects where the `Alias` property is grouped by the `Value` string value. Like this:

```
MyAlias1, MyAlias2, MyAlias3
     - Value string which is the same for above three aliases

MyAlias4, MyAlias5
     - Value string which is the same for above three aliases
```

What I have so far is:

```
var groups = lst.GroupBy(x => new { x.Alias, x.Value });
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    @group.Value
}
```

But I'm not sure what to do from there, to actually show them as grouped items.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to group by the value, then for each group you can print out what you need:

```
@{ var groups = lst.GroupBy(x => x.Value); }

@foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var aliasString = String.Join(",", group.Select(x => x.Alias));
    <p>@aliasString</p>
    <p>- @group.Key</p>
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brian! :-) Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here is grouping

```
var groups = lst.GroupBy(x => x.Value);
```

Here is displaying

```
@foreach(var group in groups)
{
    <h3>@group.Key</h3>
    <ul>
    @foreach(var alias in group)
    {
        <li>@alias.Alias</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

BTW it's better to create ViewModels in controller, then doing Linq in view:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Aliases { get; set; } // if you need concatenated string 
}
```

In controller:

```
var model = from x in lst
            group x by x.Value into g
            select new FooViewModel {
               Value = g.Key,
               Aliases = String.Join(", ", g.Select(i => i.Alias))
            };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I agree with ViewModels in controller. I'm going to refactor a bit ;-)

Comment: @bomortensen I've updated answer with displaying items sample